# How to import windows.h as module correctly

Tags: c++, module, c++20

mybar.ixx

```
export module mybar;

#include "windows.h"

export
double trywinapi() {
    MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo;
    memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo);
    return memInfo.ullTotalPageFile;
}
```

main.cpp

```
import mybar;

#include "windows.h"

void main() {
    trywinapi();
}
```

And visual studio 2019 compile error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GlobalMemoryStatusEx@4::<!mybar> referenced in function "double __cdecl trywinapi(void)" (?trywinapi@@YANXZ::<!mybar>)

Comment: Are you linking with `Kernel32.lib` as documented here (see Requirements section)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex

Comment: @RichardCritten yes,I can call trywinapi() when not using c++20 module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global module fragment goes **before** the module name:

```
module;
#include<windows.h>
export module mybar;
export double trywinapi() {…}
```

Comment: #include<windows.h> goes before export module mybar works.

Answer (score 2):

I still found many warnings by including `<windows.h>` in a C++ module and building for Debug/x64, which were dealt with like so:

**Ignore external library warnings**

*mybar.cpp*

```
module;
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#include <windows.h>
#pragma pop(0)
export module mybar;
```

This would still output a warning:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9531,5): warning C5105: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior

**Update Windows SDK**

The warning above apparently was a [regression issue](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/std:c17-generates-warning-compiling-Win/1249671?preview=true) which was resolved by updating the SDK to [Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0), version 2104](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) and making sure the Visual Studio project utilized the last Windows SDK in:

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `General` > `Windows SDK Version`

Done.

**My Environment**

```
Edition Windows 11 Home
Update 21H2
OS build 22000.51
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 421.16300.0.3

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview
Version 17.0.0 Preview 1.1
VisualStudio.17.Preview/17.0.0-pre.1.1+31423.177
Version 4.8.04161
```